Joint equidistribution of $\operatorname{maj}$ and $\operatorname{inv}$ on $S_n$
Let $S_n$ denote the set of all permutations of $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$. So my question if whether there is a simple argument/proof that the major index of a permutation $\sigma \in S_n$
$$\operatorname{maj}(\sigma) = \sum_{i:\, \sigma(i) > \sigma(i+1)} i$$
and inversion number
$$\operatorname{inv}(\sigma) = \sum_{i<j:\, \sigma(i) > \sigma(j)} 1$$
have symmetric joint distribution on $S_n$, namely
$$\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} x^{\operatorname{inv}(\sigma)} y^{\operatorname{maj}(\sigma)} = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} x^{\operatorname{maj}(\sigma)} y^{\operatorname{inv}(\sigma)}$$
I am aware of Foata's bijection and how this follows from that (I want to avoid using this), Carlitz's insertion proof of the equidistribution of $\operatorname{inv}$ and $\operatorname{maj}$ (though I don't know if and how that could be used to prove the above) and this paper (I don't think this has what I am looking for).
I was wrecking my brain how to do it with inversion tables (like in the above paper) but couldn't come up with anything. Ideally a bijection that takes (major index, inversion number) to (inversion number, major index) would be the most plausible solution, but I can't think of one. Perhaps someone could give me a hint on this.
Thanks in advance!
(I am not a mathematician, just a hobby of mine.)
